# Why Apple Health app is an inactive data source?

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

I'm developing app based on Health Kit and after some time it stopped receiving completion blocks from HealthKit. In Health app it figures as inactive data source and is not listed in apps allowed to read data, despite permission to read it is switched on.
Is there a way to fix that? 
Is it because of query limit, some app blacklisting?

I couldn't find any documentation about this state.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using [HKObserverQuery](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkobserverquery), it will try three times (at increasing time intervals) before giving up and no longer sending notifications of new data.  You may need to execute the completionHandler passed with the notification earlier; there is some dispute as to how much time can pass before the block is executed for a successful response to the notification.

I don't know how to clear the inactive application state; presumably, deleting the application from Health and then asking for permission again should do it.